# How to name a foreign key in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, attributes, foreign-keys, fluent

It seems that Entity Framework Core doesn't respect the custom name of the foreign key I specified as property attribute. I'm a bit concerned because I thought it initially worked..

1-to-many relation between `CollectionModel` and `ItemModel` (over-simplified example):

```
[Table("Collections")]
public class CollectionModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    public string name {get; set; }
    
    public List<ItemModel> Items { get; set; }
}

[Table("Items")]
public class ItemModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    [ForeignKey("FK_Item_CollectionId")] // No sure if it actually respects the convention..
    public int CollectionId { get; set; }
}
```

Basically, it corresponds to this [exampel](https://entityframework.net/foreign-key) (Entity Framework 6 though). I've already came across some stackoverflow threads which some Fluent API use, but would prefer avoiding them (ie I got some other issues..) When I migrate the domain (which is in a separate project from the Entity Framework one) I get the following name `FK_Items_Collections_ItemModelId` which is a bit too long.

Am I missing something?

Thanks for any insights.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any attributes in the case below, when Key matches Property name + Id

```
public class Parent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int ParentId { get; set; }

    public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

migration for code above generates

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "Children",
    columns: table => new
    {
        Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
            .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
        ParentId = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
    },
    constraints: table =>
    {
        table.PrimaryKey("PK_Children", x => x.Id);
        table.ForeignKey(
            name: "FK_Children_Parents_ParentId",
            column: x => x.ParentId,
            principalTable: "Parents",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
    });
```

If you change Key property name to a different one, EF won't be able to resolve key for it, so you have to manually specify it via annotation.

```
public class Parent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int MyKey { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("MyKey")]
    public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

You could use fluent method to change constraint name

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Child>()
    .HasOne(x => x.Parent)
    .WithMany(x => x.Children)
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.MyKey)
    .HasConstraintName("My_Key_name");
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Apparently I got it completely wrong... I moved to something else and will get into Entity Framework soon.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a correct way to use annotations for creating foreign key. You should create something like this:

```
[Table("Collections")]
public class CollectionModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    public string name {get; set; }
    
    [ForeignKey("FK_Item_CollectionId")]
    public List<ItemModel> Items { get; set; }
}

[Table("Items")]
public class ItemModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    
    public int FK_Item_CollectionId { get; set; }
}
```